# (C/C++) struct initalization syntax

Tags: c++, c, syntax, struct, initialization

When I make my own struct, say:

```
struct myStruct{
    int data1;
    int data2;
    string data3;
}
```

I can initialize an instance of type myStruct like this:

```
myStruct instance1;
```

So my question is, **why am I often seeing "struct" written during the initialization of a struct?** 
Maybe that's an inaccurate statement so here is an example of what I mean:

```
/*This is a tiny program that checks
  to see if a file exists in
  the current working directory. */

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const string FILENAME = data.txt;

int main(){

    struct stat fileStatus; //<-- HERE HERE HERE!
    if (FileExists(FILENAME, fileStatus)){
        cout << "File Does Exist" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "File Does NOT Exist" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool FileExists(const string & fileName,struct stat & fileStatus){

    bool fileDoesNotExist = stat (fileName.c_str(), &fileStatus);
    return !fileDoesNotExist;
}
```

>
    LINE 13: struct stat fileStatus;

**Is this something that was done in C for some reason?

Something with a macro or a typedef?**
I just don't understand why this is the way it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a C thing; there's no good reason to continue to do it in C++.<sup>1</sup>

In C, `struct` is part of the typename, e.g.:

```
struct foo { int x; };
```

defines a type called `struct foo`.  In C++, it defines a type called `foo`.  In C, you can usually hide this irritation behind a typedef:

```
typedef struct foo { int x; } foo;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> At least, not in code that couldn't possibly also be compiled as C (such as the example in your question).

Comment: This is one part of C and C++ that are fundamentally incompatible. If you were to have `struct A { int x; }; typedef struct A B; struct B { int x; };` it is legal C but not legal C++.

Comment: `struct foo` and `foo` are two different things in C++, too. See the classic example of `struct stat` and function `stat`.

Answer (score -3):

You can do what you want by instead calling it like this:

```
typedef struct mystruct
{
    int itema;
    int itemb;
Etc...
}* mystruct;
```

So that's whenever you make a mystruct item it creates a pointer to your struct, else you have to call your struct by

struct mystruct *object;

Comment: Typedefing `struct mystruct *` to `mystruct` sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: So bad, in fact, that I'm sure a Java programmer thought of it.